# Laravel 4 Route::resource issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm new to Laravel, I have a route in my routes.php file like this:

```
    <?php
Route::resource('search', 'SearchController');                
?>
```

and I have the controller app/controllers/SearchController.php that looks like this:

```
<?php

    class SearchController extends \BaseController {

        protected $layout = 'layouts.master';
        public function create() {}

        public function store(){}

        public function index(){
            return View::make('hello');
        }
    }
    ?>
```

I previously had a controller with unrestful methods name SearchController. I renamed that one to OldSearchController and updated the routes.

and a file hello.php in app/views.

but, whenever I try to access the page via `http://localhost/search`, I get the following error:

```
BadMethodCallException 
Method [index] does not exist.
```

what else needs to be done?

Comment: Is that all you have on the `app/routes.php` file?

Comment: yes, just the single route

Comment: Let's try something more simple: `Route::get('/search', function() { return 'It works!'; });`.
You have `mod_rewrite` working, right?

Comment: so, I can make a controller, FooController with a corresponding route and the same logic and it works. Is SearchController defined by default in Laravel possibly? if so, where would it be?

Comment: I just tested your route and controller on a fresh installation of Laravel 4 and it worked like a charm. I'm searching something else that can be causing this problem

Comment: so, i think I found the problem, but It's still there. I made a new version of SearchController and renamed the old version to OldSearchController. OldSearchController was routed using Route::get instead of route resource.  Once I deleted OldSearchController, the error became include(/var/www/ppdb/app/controllers/OldSearchController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory.  I can't find any reference to OldSearchController in any file in the project. why would it be looking for the old one? does it store something in the database?

Comment: Try this: `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan dump-autoload`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52135/discussion-between-chris-drappier-and-vsmoraes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, the following command did the trick:

```
php artisan dump-autoload
```

Probably something happened during the installation.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is run this:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Your classes are being cached and there is likely a conflict going on with your previous SearchController.